# Finding smallest value from users array inputs

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose a user is asked to enter doubles for the weekdays,

```
double[] userInput= new double[5];
String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

for(int index = 0; index <= 11; index ++) {
    System.out.println("Enter " + days[index] + " double amount: ");
    userInput[Index] = scan.nextDouble();
}
```

This gets us something like

```
Enter Monday double amount: 
Enter Tuesday double amount:
Enter Wednesday double amount:
Enter Thursday double amount:
Enter Friday double amount:
```

Given the users values, how do I find the lowest double if I must use the method

```
public static int getLowestDouble(double[] numArray){

}
```

so that, in the main function, I can call the getLowestDouble function for this print message

```
System.out.println(days[] + " has the lowest value of " + getLowestDouble(userInput));
```

I have tried writing into the getLowestDouble method as follows

```
public static int getLowestDouble(double[] numArray){
double min = 0;
                double MINIMUM = 0;
                int MINIMUM_1 = 0;
                for (int i = MINIMUM_1; i < numArray.length; i++) {
                    if(MINIMUM_1 > numArray[i]) {
                        MINIMUM_1 = i;
                    }
                }
                return MINIMUM_1;
}
```

but I only get the highest value, of course. I already knew this wouldn't work, but I know it's obligatory to show attempts.

Comment: `days[index]` is going to give you an index out of bounds exception

Comment: yeah I know, I just wasn't sure how to describe the day must be included in the print before stating its value

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to me why `getLowestDouble()` would return an `int` and not a `double` seeing as `numArray` holds only doubles. Why would you want this?

Comment: it's for an assignment. I want to post the full context of the code but i cant do that publicly because my professor will likely catch it.

Comment: The problem isn't that you're asking for help online. The problem is that you're asking people to do your homework for you. This is something that can be googled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the lowest number, store the first value in the array as the lowest, then continuously check the rest of the values in the array to see if they are less than the current lowest number, and if they are, then set the current lowest number to the new lowest number.

```
public static int getLowestDouble(double[] numArray){
    double lowest = numArray[0];
    for (double check : numArray)
        if (check < lowest)
           lowest = check;
    return (int) lowest; 
}
```

Although, you will see your final result decimals truncated because of the return type in the method (int), so you might want to change that to a double, and remove the integer cast in the return statement.

Comment: You shouldn't, but look at it now ^

Comment: oh sorry, the function must return an int. My assignment requires that

Comment: also, i dont know if this makes a difference, but i'm using eclipse

Comment: Then there, that won't throw a type mismatch.

Comment: Ohh sorry, yes in the for loop, I did not see that, I thought you meant in the return line

Comment: I've changed it accordingly, youre welcome for your hw

Comment: I caught the error I was making. Your code is working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Java8+ solution would be as follows:

```
public static double getLowestDouble(final double[] numArray) {
    return Arrays.stream(numArray).min().orElse(0);
}
```

Comment: Which Java version are using? This would only work with 8+.